# active sheet column width

Tags: excel, worksheet, column-width, dynamic-columns, vba

The second line tells me it is not supported. I pretty much got this from the Microsoft website.  Not sure what is wrong with it.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add

ActiveSheet.Columnns("A").ColumnWidth = 21
```

Comment: `Columnns`-->`Columns`

Comment: oh geez thanks. Maybe time for a break

Comment: Could be the double 'n' in your 'Columnns'